# select values where item in selected item from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server

table Elements

```
ElementsName  ElementsCode
aaa           25
bbb           84
ccc           2
ddd           69
eee           158
```

table ElementsToCalc

```
Elements  SerialNum
25,2      1
69        2
158,84,2  3
```

I have the above two tables and want to select values from Elements by ElementsToCalc like code below

```
select * 
from Elements
where ElementsCode in (select Elements 
                       from ElementsToCalc 
                       where SerialNum = 1)
```

and get nothing...

I think it'll works like below but not.

```
select * 
from Elements
where ElementsCode in (25,2)
```

how could I get this code work like what I want it to be?

Comment: maybe `where ElementsCode in (25,2)` ??

Comment: you shouldn't be storing comma separated values in a single column to begin with. That was a bad design decision.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: sorry for misleading..., the ElementsName shall be ElementsCode

Comment: hmm, I didn't think too much at begining... I'm useing MSSql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS SQL Server 2016 and later you could use [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) to get the values from the varchar.

**Example snippet:**

```
declare @ElementsToCalc table (SerialNum int identity(1,1) primary key, [Elements] varchar(30));
insert into @ElementsToCalc ([Elements]) values 
('25,2'),
('69'),
('158,84,2');

declare @Elements table (ElementsName varchar(10), ElementsCode int);
insert into @Elements (ElementsName, ElementsCode) values
('aaa',25),
('bbb',84),
('ccc',2),
('ddd',69),
('eee',158);

with CALC as
(
 select SerialNum, try_cast(value as int) as Element
 from @ElementsToCalc ec
 cross apply string_split([Elements],',') spl
 where SerialNum = 1
)
select * 
from @Elements e
where ElementsCode in (select distinct Element from CALC);
```

If STRING_SPLIT is not available in your version then you could use an XML trick in the CTE.

```
with CALC as
(
  select SerialNum, x.value('.','int') as Element
  from (
   select SerialNum, cast('<x>'+replace([Elements],',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML) as XElements
   from ElementsToCalc
   where SerialNum = 1
  ) q
  cross apply XElements.nodes('/x') as n(x)
)
select * 
from Elements e
where ElementsCode in (select distinct Element from CALC);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get your query to work you can use a query as below. But the better option would be to redesign your schema as in the above comment.

```
select * 
  from Elements a
  join ElementsToCalc b  
    on ','+b.Elements+',' like '%,'+cast(a.ElementsCode as varchar(100))+',%'
 where b.serialnum=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tfn_Split]
(
    @string VARCHAR(8000) ,
    @SerialNum INT
)
RETURNS TABLE 
As
Return (
    SELECT str1.value , @SerialNum as SerialNum
    FROM  STRING_SPLIT(@string, ',') str1 
)  

DECLARE @ElementsToCalc TABLE (Elements nvarchar(50), SerialNum INT)
INSERT INTO @ElementsToCalc(Elements, SerialNum) VALUES('25,2',1)
INSERT INTO @ElementsToCalc(Elements, SerialNum) VALUES('69',2)
INSERT INTO @ElementsToCalc(Elements, SerialNum) VALUES('158,84,2',3)  

DECLARE @Elements TABLE (ElementsName nvarchar(50), ElementsCode INT)
INSERT INTO @Elements(ElementsName, ElementsCode) VALUES('aaa',25)
INSERT INTO @Elements(ElementsName, ElementsCode) VALUES('bbb',84)
INSERT INTO @Elements(ElementsName, ElementsCode) VALUES('ccc',2)
INSERT INTO @Elements(ElementsName, ElementsCode) VALUES('ddd',69)
INSERT INTO @Elements(ElementsName, ElementsCode) VALUES('eee',158)  

SELECT *
FROM   @Elements
WHERE  elementscode IN
       ( SELECT tb1.value
         FROM   @ElementsToCalc AS elc
                CROSS apply ( SELECT spl.serialnum,
                                     spl.value
                              FROM   dbo.Tfn_split ( elc.elements, elc.serialnum )     spl ) tb1
         WHERE  elc.serialnum = 1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

For the query you are using to work you should modify the second table as follows

```
Elements  SerialNum
25        1
2         1
69        2
158       3
84        3
2         3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try query like below.

```
select * 
from Elements E
where EXISTS (select Elements 
              from ElementsToCalc ETC
              where ETC.SerialNum = 1 
              AND E.ElementsCode IN STRING_SPLIT(ETC.Elements, ','))
```

OR

```
select * 
from Elements E
where EXISTS (select Elements 
              from ElementsToCalc ETC
              where ETC.SerialNum = 1 
              AND Charindex(',' + ETC.Elements + ',', ',' + E.ElementsCode + ',') > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using `EXISTS` and `CHARINDEX()`

```
CREATE TABLE T1
    ([ElementsName] varchar(3), [ElementsCode] int);

INSERT INTO T1
    ([ElementsName], [ElementsCode])
VALUES
    ('aaa', 25),
    ('bbb', 84),
    ('ccc', 2),
    ('ddd', 69),
    ('eee', 158);

CREATE TABLE T2
    ([Elements] varchar(8), [SerialNum] int);

INSERT INTO T2
    ([Elements], [SerialNum])
VALUES
    ('25,2', 1),
    ('69', 2),
    ('158,84,2', 3);
SELECT *
FROM T1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM T2
              WHERE T2.SerialNum = 1
              AND CHARINDEX(',' + CAST(T1.ElementsCode AS VARCHAR(11)) + ',', 
                            ',' + T2.Elements + ','
                           ) > 0
             );
```

**Returns:**

```
+--------------+--------------+
| ElementsName | ElementsCode |
+--------------+--------------+
| aaa          |           25 |
| ccc          |            2 |
+--------------+--------------+
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10bf79572a19321c60b66eb0ec170538)**